# Does my lens have lens corrections table for photoshop?

Tags: lens, adobe-camera-raw, adobe, lens-correction, nikon-d80

I have got my first DSLR, Nikon D80 and altough I am happy to get a DSLR with dual dials, pentaprism and best of all, CCD sensor but the lens that came with it has a problem.

I have searched the net and [the supported lenses page of The Adobe website](https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/kb/supported-lenses.html) and it seems like there are no lens aberration correction table for it.

Is this all? I will never be able to fix the aberrations easily and I have to learn fine tuning or maybe there is an hero that made a custom/homemade preset settings for it?

My lens is Nikon DX AF-S NIKKOR 18-135mm 1:3-5.6G ED

I want to know if there is an lens corrections table for my lens or not. A file that I can drag to the photoshop or maybe an spreadsheet that lists custom settings I should apply when manually setting the lens corrections profile.

Comment: I -*think* "is it really it" means "is this just how it is"? But I don't want to presume. DOU, can you confirm?

Comment: Or "is that all there is to it?"

Comment: @mattdm you are right

Comment: I just want to know if lens corrections table exists for my lens or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your lens is not on Adobe's list of supported lenses, official Adobe lens correction data for your lens either does not exist or is not provided to the public.  Other options include:

- Your lens may be included in the [Lensfun](https://lensfun.github.io/) database, which is used by some non-Adobe software to apply lens corrections.
- You can use Hugin to correct an image taken with your lens.  The same `pto` file can be used to correct other images taken with the same lens at the same focal length.
- Ken Rockwell [provides](https://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/18-135.htm) values you can type into Photoshop's lens distortion filter.